# PHP OOP5 - Cannot add context to object via method

Tags: php, oop

i got this class:

```
class Trajectory{
    private $points = array();

    public function __construct(){
    }

    public function addPoint(Point $myPoint){
        $this->points[] = $myPoint; // line 20
    }
}
```

when i try to run the method addPoint(), I'm getthing this error:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /index.php on line 20
```

I tried changing it to:

```
$points[] = $myPoint;
```

but then the Trajectory's $point array doesn't change, instead its creating a new $points array each time i use the addPoint method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could not call this method as static method.

You should call it on an instance of the Class.

```
$trajectory = new Trajectory();
$trajectory->addPoint($point);
```

Instead of `Trajectory::addPoint($point);`